# Check for a definition of a macro inside a macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have this code:

```
#define NAME MY_APP
#define ENABLE NAME ## _ENABLE
```

I want to check if the macro that `ENABLE` expands to is defined, i.e., if `MY_APP_ENABLE` is defined. Is this possible using **C** macros?

Comment: make your question simpler not easy to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the construct `defined` to check if a macro is defined, but it's only possible to use this in preprocessor expressions. It's possible to write a macro that expands to this construct. For example:

```
#define MY_APP_ENABLED

#define IS_DEFINED(x) defined(x ## _ENABLED)

#if IS_DEFINED(MY_APP)
#error "YES"
#else
#error "NO"
#endif
```

The above will issue `YES` when compiled. If `MY_APP_ENABLED` isn't defined, `NO` will be issued.

**Update:** The following version will work when NAME is defined to MY_APP. The extra level of indirections allows `NAME` to be expanded to `MY_APP` before it's concatenated with `_ENABLED`:

```
#define MY_APP_ENABLED

#define IS_DEFINED0(x) defined(x ## _ENABLED)
#define IS_DEFINED(x) IS_DEFINED0(x)

#define NAME MY_APP

#if IS_DEFINED(NAME)
#error "YES"
#else
#error "NO"
#endif
```

Comment: This almost answers my question, however I need the MY_APP to be a content of another macro.

    #define NAME MY_APP
    #if IS_DEFINED(???NAME??? ## _ENABLED)

And it should expand to #if defined(MY_APP_ENABLED)

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what I need. Thank you. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

No.  In particular, the suggested

```
#ifdef NAME ## _ENABLE
```

will not work, according to *6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement*, which says

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not reprocessed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.